# How to do this JSP code <%= session.getAttribute("attributeName") %> in Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, syntax

How to do this JSP code `<%= session.getAttribute("attributeName") %>` in Expression Language
where stuff goes like `${blabla}`

Forgot to say that I actually tried the `${sessionScope.attributeName}`, btw the attribute value is a String and was set by `session.setAttribute("attributeName", "EditSession123");` and to check on that the value was sent right I created a jsp 1.0 file and used  `<%= session.getAttribute("attributeName") %>` which was working  but when I used JSP 2.0 nothing appears.

I'm beginning to question my header definitions ? it's auto generated from Eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
        pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

hello ${sessionScope.attributeName}

${pageContext.servletContext.serverInfo}

</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: `${sessionScope.attributeName}`?

Comment: that's what I thought but it didn't work, I'm beginning to wonder if there is another reason like the header of .jsp file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ops, :S  session is set as false, I should have read the eclipse generated code carefully,